# Maven concat files specific files in a directory

Tags: java, xml, maven, ant, maven-plugin

I have a directory with unknown depth and folder names.

```
>A
-> AB
--> configuration.xml
--> ABC
---> configuration.xml
-> AD
--> configuration.xml
-> allconfigurations.xml
```

I need a maven plugin to concat all the `configuration.xml` files and create `allconfigurations.xml` file in the root. Unfortunately folder names and depth is unknown. It would be great to accomplish it within the `pom.xml` file without needing any other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While struggling I realized that the real problem is to put a header and footer for the compiled `allconfigurations.xml` file, since each `configuration.xml` file is a fragment and when I concat all of them together resulting xml is not a valid xml.

here is the case;
an xml file is something like:

```
<Configuration xmlns="abc">
     ...
    <connectionTimeoutInMs>240000</connectionTimeoutInMs>
    <socketTimeoutInMs>240000</socketTimeoutInMs>
    <persist>false</persist>
    <internal>false</internal>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

and putting many of them is not valid thus result xml must be something like;

```
<AllConfigurations xmlns="abc">
    ...
    <Configuration xmlns="abc">
       ...
    </Configuration >    
    ...
<AllConfigurations xmlns="abc">
```

so the first and last lines must be added to the result.

here is the solution I came up with;

```
            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <!--<phase>process-resources</phase>-->
                    <!--<phase>compile</phase>-->
                    <configuration>
                        <target>
                            <concat destfile="${project.basedir}/.../allConfigurations.xml"
                                    force="yes">
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/...">
                                    <include name="xmlHeaderForConfiguration"></include>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/...">
                                    <include name="**/configuration.xml"></include>
                                </fileset>
                                <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/...">
                                    <include name="xmlFooterForConfiguration"></include>
                                </fileset>
                            </concat>

                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

where xmlHeaderForConfiguration is a file with content; `<AllConfigurations xmlns="abc">` and xmlHeaderForConfiguration  has `</AllConfigurations>`

Answer (score 2):

just a quick google for you: the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#XmlAppendingTransformer) with the XmlAppendingTransformer could help.

sample config is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6195089/520615)