# Merge same properties in application.properties and application.yaml

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have two properties files: application.properties:

```
spring.datasources[0].url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/earch
spring.datasources[0].username = postgres
spring.datasources[0].password = 
spring.dataSources[0].driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.dataSources[0].liquibase.enabled=false

spring.dataSources[1].tenantId=db4
spring.dataSources[1].url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_liquibase?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.dataSources[1].username=root
spring.dataSources[1].password=
spring.dataSources[1].driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.dataSources[1].spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.charset=utf8
spring.dataSources[1].spring.jpa.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
spring.dataSources[1].spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.dataSources[1].spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.dataSources[1].liquibase.enabled=true
spring.dataSources[1].liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/master/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

and application.yaml:

```
spring:
 dataSources:
  - tenantId: db5
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db4
    username: postgres
    password: 
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    liquibase:
      enabled: true
      change-log: classpath:db/yaml-change/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
```

and config file:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSources")
    @Primary
    public Map<Object, Object> getDataSources(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        return dataSourceProperties.getDataSources().stream().map(dataSourceProperty -> {
            DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .url(dataSourceProperty.getUrl())
                    .username(dataSourceProperty.getUsername())
                    .password(dataSourceProperty.getPassword())
                    .driverClassName(dataSourceProperty.getDriverClassName())
                    .build();
            return new TenantIdDataSource(dataSourceProperty.getTenantId(), dataSource);
        }).collect(Collectors.toMap(TenantIdDataSource::getTenantId, TenantIdDataSource::getDataSource));
    }
```

now parsed only yaml properties. If drop yaml prop, parsed properties from application.properties

is it possible to merge this properties from two files to dataSourceProperties?

Comment: You could configure your data source as you want. In your case configure data source in yaml file is enough. Defining the same settings in different places looks strange a little bit and redundant. My advice is - try to keep your setting separate from your code, in application.yaml or application.properties etc.

Comment: You can try to use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598314/merge-properties-files-with-maven-assembly

Comment: Also you can try rename one file (`application1.properties` for example). Reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862357/1943863

Comment: i can't rename any files, besides this application files contain many others keys. and this project is legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the same DataSourceProperties class for example, DSProps:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring1")
@PropertySource({"application.yml"})
public class DSProps {

    private List<DataSourceProperty> dataSources = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring")
@PropertySource({"application.properties"})
public class DataSourceProperties {

    private List<DataSourceProperty> dataSources = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

and in the method getDataSources add one line:

```
dataSourceProperties.getDataSources().addAll(dsProps.getDataSources());
```

of course in the application.yaml prefix must be different