# Gatling: How can I eliminate the adding of the timestamp to the name of output folder?

Tags: scala, maven, pom.xml, simulation, gatling

I would a specific name to the output directory of my gatling test without timestamp. I use maven method. Help please.

Comment: It looks like this is hardcoded functionality which cannot be changed even if using Gatling directly without maven plugin. https://groups.google.com/g/gatling/c/_WHiZrPJI7s
I guess only possibility could be renaming the folder afterwards, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998596/renaming-resources-in-maven

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for your help